# View pager in main activity with tabs is not showing fragment completely

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, adview

I got a main activity with tabs layout and view pager.
This view pager is linked with different fragments.
At the bottom of the fragment layout i have adview view but when the view pager is showing that fragments it is not showing some bottom part of the fragment.
Can you help me in correcting the attributes of my xml to get the proper layout.
Below are the xml codes for main activity and fragment.

Main activity xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Fragment xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#EF9A9A"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
tools:context="com.example.visheshdube.indianrailways.Fragments.Pnr">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/pnrNumber"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:ems="20"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="10 Digit PNR"
    android:inputType="numberSigned"
    android:maxLength="10"
    android:numeric="integer"
    android:phoneNumber="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:textColorHint="#BDBDBD"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/pnrButton"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pnrNumber"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/pnrNumber"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pnrNumber"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:text="OK" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_below="@+id/pnrNumber"


    android:padding="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/pnrDetails">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pnrJourneyDetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:baselineAligned="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pnrPassengerDetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


        android:layout_below="@+id/pnrJourneyDetails"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/pnrPassengerList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp" />
    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#223344"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pnrDetails"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"


    >

</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

[Fragment xml view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDJ2P.png)

[Main activity view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AN4a1.png)

Comment: You need a ScrollView, perhaps?

Comment: ok , will try to put scroll view .

Answer (score 0):

Make your viewpager like this:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/viewpager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Comment: Stankovitch, fill parent doesnt helped, even i also tried to use fill parent for the root element also. i think scroll view will help.

Answer (score 0):

changed my main activity layout code to the below one, and it worked for me.

Main activity .xml

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tabs"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, using ScrollView within CoordinatorLayout may cause the screen is unable to scroll. So use NestedScrollView instead.